# Mongo $IfNull doesn't do what it is expected to do

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection "structure" with a document :

```
{
    "case" : {
        "version" : 3,
        "key" : 1
    },
    "salle" : {
        "version" : 2,
        "key" : 1
    }
}
```

And I try a $cond aggregation with $ifNull operator :

```
db.structure.aggregate([
{
    "structure" : {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$ifNull": ["$salle", true]
            },
            "then": "$case.key",
            "else": "$salle.key"
        }
    }
}
])
```

The trouble is that $ifNull always return true and displays $case.key, while $salle is not null

The most surprising is that I get the right response with $not operator :

```
db.structure.aggregate([
{
    "structure" : {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$not": {
                    "$ifNull": ["$salle", false]
                }
            },
            "then": "$case.key",
            "else": "$salle.key"
        }
    }
}
])
```

Can anyone can explain me what's going on ?